# How can textView setText out of onCreate?

Tags: java, android, swing, mobile, text

```
import com.example.zulkuf.sdukampus.fragments.DayKey;

/**
 * Created by zulkuf on 24.4.2017.
 */    
public class BusItemClickActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ImageView imClick;
    public TextView tv1Click, tv2Click, tv3Click;
    private String busClickTime;
    private String busClickNumber;
    private String busClickRoute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bus_item_click_activity);

        imClick = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBusClickNumberImage);
        tv1Click = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBusClickNumber);
        tv2Click = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BusClickTime);
        tv3Click = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BusClickRoute);
    }

    public void busInformation(String[] info){
         busClickNumber = info[0].toString();
        busClickTime = info[1].toString();
        busClickRoute = info[2].toString();

        tv1Click.setText(busClickNumber);
        tv2Click.setText(busClickTime);
        tv3Click.setText(busClickRoute);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant apply these texts in textview. how can fix this ?

Comment: I cant apply these texts in textview. how can fix this ?

Comment: That code seems fine to me. what is the problem?

Comment: Post your xml code and also full BusItemClickActivity class

Answer (score 0):

From your comment/answer it seems that one of the `findViewById` is returning `null`. Which happens when a view is not found. Make sure that the id's in your layout file are the same as in the java code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked them. There is a id in my layout file